# What is the best way to store option in a NoSQL db?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a list of options that I let my users to select from and they are allowed to select multiple of them. I want to store that in Firebase db which is a NoSQL db. Should I store it this way:

```
{
  "selection": {
    "option1": true,
    "option2": false,
    "option3": true
  }
}
```

or this way:

```
{
  "selection": ["option1", "option3"]
}
```

Either way, what are the benefits or disadvantages of doing such way?

Answer (score 0):

> the second way:

```
{
  "selection": ["option1", "option3"]
}
```

Here you'll not have to worry about options that user has not selected. You only store the ones that the user agreed for. This way, your user object can be minimal.

Plus, here you can do all the things that were possible in method 1. Like for checking if a particular key is present of not, you can use arr.indexOf("key"), if >=0 then YES else NO.

P.S. unless you want to know it later that "What options were offered to the user when the object was created?"; you are good to go with 2nd way.

Else there is no problem as such in either way, just a way to keep User object minimal. That's it.